# Angular: use data service with TLS/SSL protocol

Tags: angular, ssl

From an Angular 4 app, I've to query a data service over https (TLS/SSL protocol with cert/key). Is there any option to run the https request directly from the Angular code? The build-in `HttpClientModule` does not have any support for it and the npm `request` module, which includes all the functionality, cannot be used from the browser.

Comment: In the begin you tell: "From an Angular 4 app, I've to query a data service over https (TLS/SSL protocol with cert/key)" and then "Is there any option to run the https request directly from the Angular code?". I think there is contradiction here, doesn't it?

Comment: @slesh: No, why should it be?

Comment: ok. Have I correctly understood that you want call API through out HTTPS in Angular4 without HttpClientModule. If so, then what is purpose you need do it?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. And the reason is quite simple, the app's data is stored within this data service :)

Comment: and why you cannot access the date in the same way? It is not clearly what the problem.

Comment: @Slesh, I'm sorry, but I don't understand your point. It's so simple: there is an app (Angular 4) which must access some data service located on a remote server. This remote server accepts only secured connections (cert/key or the pfx file and a password). Angular does not have any build-in support for this kind of https-connections. So my question is, whether there is some way to achieve this.

Comment: I got it. Ok, then you don't need any specific libraries, you can access secured services by https by default, all required work the browser will do: it will open encrypted connection with that service. So, you can work with secured service as with unsecured.